# In OLS, what is the probability that a coefficient is spuriously significant?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value

I was asked this during an interview, but I don't know much about statistical testing for OLS. Consider OLS with $P$ predictors:

$$
y = \beta_0 + x_1\beta_1 + x_2\beta_2 + \dots + x_P\beta_P + \varepsilon.
$$

Imagine we observe that $\beta_i$ has a p-value $\leq 0.05$. What is probability that this happens at random?

**What I tried:**

Let $r_i$ be probability that $\beta_i$ is significant. Then the probability that all the parameters are insignificant is

$$
(1-r_1)(1-r_2) \dots (1-r_P),
$$

if we assume the parameters are independent. The probability that at least one of the parameters is significant is

$$
1 - (1-r_1)(1-r_2) \dots (1-r_P).
$$

I ran out of time here, but I think the obvious conclusion is just to write

$$
\text{probability a param. is signif. by chance} = 1 - 0.95^P
$$

So for example, with 10 parameters, the probability that we see a significant parameter by chance is over 40%. Is my reasoning correct? Any points or assumptions I am missing?

Comment: Maybe the question was designed to discern whether an interviewee can recognize the description of a p-value.

Comment: The question cannot be answered with the information given, because the p-value depends on $\beta_i$ as well as its estimate $\hat\beta_i.$  For your calculations to apply you must assume both (1) all $\beta_i=0$ and (2) all the variables are uncorrelated.

Answer (score 0):

There are some difficulties when it comes to answering this. For instance, how probable is it that the true coefficient is zero? If the true coefficient almost certainly is not zero, then there is an argument that the probability of a suprious significant coefficient is zero, since every rejection of the null hypothesis $H_0: \beta_i=0$ is correct. This is part of what the comment by whuber means about how the p-value depends on both the estimate and the true value. This is kind of blending frequentist and Bayesian thinking, yes, but the question phrasing seems to invite that.

My take on this interview question is that it is a test of whether or not you know how p-values behave under the null hypothesis. If you repeatedly test when the null hypothesis really is true, tests should give a $U(0,1)$ distribution of p-values. I demonstrate below in a simulation where $mu=0$ is true, and the p-values give the desired uniform distribution on $(0,1)$.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 10
R <- 10000
p <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
  x <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)
  p[i] <- t.test(x, mu = 0)$p.value
}
d <- data.frame(
  p_value = p,
  CDF = ecdf(p)(p)
)
ggplot(d, aes(x = p_value, y = CDF)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0)
```

[image: U(0,1) CDF]

With that in mind, the distribution under the null hypothesis of p-values is $U(0,1)$, and if $X\sim U(0,1)$, then $P(X<x)=x$. Consequently, $P(X<0.05)=0.05$, and there is a $5\%$ chance of observing a suprious significant coefficient. If you want to consider multiple coefficients, assume independence, and assume all coefficients to truly equal zero, then I agree with your calculation of $1-0.95^p$, where $p$ is the number of coefficients. However, I think the discussion of the uniform distribution of p-values under the null hypothesis is the key part of this.